# Gemset: Rails is not currently installed on this system.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gemset

```
macbook$ rvm gemset list_all

gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-p320 (found in /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320)
   global


gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
   nice
   global     

macbook$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@nice
Using /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@nice with gemset global
macbook$ rails --version
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

macbook$ sudo gem install rails
1 gem successfully installed.
macbook$ rails --version
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

Comment: Try `gem install rails` instead of `sudo gem install rails`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
macbook$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194
Using /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
macbook$ rails --version
Rails 3.2.11
```