# RVM Gemset: Rails is not currently installed on this system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I have latest RVM installed in OX 10.9.

```
$ rvm rubies

* ruby-1.9.3-p545 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-2.1.1 (found in /Users/rajveershekhawat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1)
(default)
global
rails403   
rails404
=> rails410
```

After this i installed rails.

```
$ gem install rails -v 4.1.0
```

It got installed. It is also there in correct location within .rvm folder. But when I try using it, system says rails is not installed.

```
$ rails -v

Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

I have tried it twice and still unable to figure out what am I am missing. Please help.
Thanks.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705373/gemset-rails-is-not-currently-installed-on-this-system) question is similar but is not helping.

Edits:

```
 $ gem list | grep rails
 rails (4.1.0)
 sprockets-rails (2.1.3)

 $ echo $PATH

 /Users/rajveershekhawat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails410/bin:/Users/rajveershekhawat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/rajveershekhawat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/rajveershekhawat/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Update:

Seems like the rails was not properly installed before. I recreated the gemset and tried to intall rails again but got some error. Then I again emptied the gemset and reinstalled rails with sudo. This resolved the issue.

Comment: What does `gem list | grep rails` give you?

Comment: It returns
rails (4.1.0)
sprockets-rails (2.1.3)

Comment: Then `rails` is definitely installed. Close all active shells and then open a new one and try `rails -v` again.

Comment: Tried. Still same thing.

Comment: enter into the project's folder and run `bundle show rails`

Comment: I am not into any project folder yet. I want to crete a new project using rails 4.1.0.

Comment: so provide output `bundle show rails`

Comment: The output was "Could not locate Gemfile". The problem was that the rails was not correctly installed. When I checked the .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails410/bin folder, rails was not there. Now I have recreated the gemset but while trying to install rails i am getting this error ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A (https://d2chzxaqi4y7f8.cloudfront.net/gems/i18n-0.6.9.gem)

Comment: ok, so provide: `which rails`, and `cat $(which rails) | head  -n 3`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.1@rails410
gem list
```

Can you find Rails here?

Why did you call `sudo gem install rails`, cant be this the problem, you do not need to use sudo.

Comment: Yes I can. Rails is there.

Comment: Oh, sori it was just suggestion.

Comment: I didn't use sudo. And even if I do i don't think it's a problem.

Comment: Yea I get it, it was just a shell suggestion. Did you list the bin folders (eg. .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails410/bin)? If you can find rails there? Are the privileges set correctly?

Comment: No, surprisingly rails is not there. Seems like rails is not installed correctly.